# LazyColumn error: LazyPagingItems<TypeVariable(T)> required but found List<T>

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging, android-paging-3, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm using the `Paging 3` library with `LazyColumn` and I want to sort the list according to the category of shopping list items. In the code below, `LazyColumn` complains that it's expecting `LazyPagingItems<TypeVariable(T)>` for the `items` property but found `List<ShoppingListItem?>`. How can I fix this?

**Composable**

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
val successItems = allItemsState.allItems?.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

LazyColumn(
    state = lazyListState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        start = 5.dp,
        end = 5.dp,
        top = 8.dp,
        bottom = 165.dp
    ),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
) {
    val groupedByCategory = successItems!!.itemSnapshotList.groupBy { it!!.category }

    groupedByCategory.forEach { (initial, shoppingListItems) ->
        item {
            Text(text = initial)
        }
        items(
            items = shoppingListItems, //Throws error at this line
            key = { item ->
                item.id
            }
        ) { item ->
            ShoppingListScreenItem(
                item = item,
                mainViewModel = shoppingListScreenViewModel,
                onNavigateToAddEditItemScreenFromItemStrip = { shoppingListItem ->
                    onNavigateToAddEditItemScreenFromItemStrip(shoppingListItem)
                },
            ) { isChecked ->
                scope.launch {
                    shoppingListScreenViewModel.changeItemChecked(
                        item,
                        isChecked
                    )
                }
            }
            Divider(color = Color.LightGray, thickness = 1.dp)
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
Type mismatch.

Required:
LazyPagingItems<TypeVariable(T)>
Found:
List<ShoppingListItem?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate `import` statement is required in this case.

If the `LazyColumn` uses a `List<T>` for the `items` DSL method, then the following import statement is required:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

But, if it uses `LazyPagingItems<TypeVariable(T)>`, then use the following import statement:

```
import androidx.paging.compose.items
```

And both imports can be used at the same time if, for example, you're using a conditional logic to load either of the collection types.

Answer (score 8):

The `items(LazyPagingItems)` function has been removed from newer versions of the library which might be why you were not able to find the import. This was done in order to make the API more flexible and to support all types of `LazyContainers`.

According to the release notes here: [Paging Compose Version 1.0.0-alpha20](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/paging#1.0.0-alpha20), here is the approach which should be used:

```
val lazyPagingItems = pager.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
  // Here we use the standard items API
  items(
    count = lazyPagingItems.itemCount,
    // Here we use the new itemKey extension on LazyPagingItems to
    // handle placeholders automatically, ensuring you only need to provide
    // keys for real items
    key = lazyPagingItems.itemKey { it.uniqueId },
    // Similarly, itemContentType lets you set a custom content type for each item
    contentType = lazyPagingItems.itemContentType { "contentType" }
  ) { index ->
    // As the standard items call provides only the index, we get the item
    // directly from our lazyPagingItems
    val item = lazyPagingItems[index]
    PagingItem(item = item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like what `V Mircan` said, it was removed. But you can write your own like:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyItemScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.paging.compose.LazyPagingItems
import androidx.paging.compose.itemContentType
import androidx.paging.compose.itemKey

fun <T: Any> LazyListScope.items(
    items: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    key: ( (T) -> Any )? = null,
    contentType: ( (T) -> Any )? = null,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(T) -> Unit
) {
    items(
        items.itemCount,
        key = items.itemKey(key),
        contentType = items.itemContentType(contentType)
    ) loop@ { i ->
        val item = items[i] ?: return@loop
        itemContent(item)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like other `items`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me Try this:**

Hi there please try it once:

```
listData?.let {
            items(it) { item ->
                ProductElement(
                    drawable = R.drawable.picture,
                    title = item.title,
                    brand = item.brand,
                    prize = "${item.price}"
                )
            }
        }
```